# Упрощение двусвязного списка

Tags: c, указатели, двусвязный-список, динамические-структуры

Можно ли этот код считать двусвязным списком? И реально ли его как-то упростить, потому что мне кажется я слишком много указателей понасоздавал.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>
struct name{
int k;
struct name *next;
struct name *prev;
};
int main(void)
{
  setlocale(LC_ALL,"RUS");
  int to;
  struct name *current,*p;
  struct name *head=NULL;
  printf("Ввод: ");
  scanf("%d",&to);
  while(to!=0)
  {
    current=(struct name *)malloc(sizeof(struct name));
    if(head==NULL)
      head=current;
    else
      p->next=current;
    current->next=NULL;
    current->k=to;
    current->prev=current;
    p=current;
    scanf("%d",&to);
  }
 }
```

Comment: Вместе с двусвязным списком почти всегда имеет смысл завести вот такую структуру `struct my_2_list { struct name *head, *tail; }` с указателями на первый и последний элементы списка и использовать ее при манипуляции со списком (в т.ч. во всех вспомогательных функциях (которых у вас пока нет,  но вскоре они наверняка появятся))

Comment: @avp Конечно появятся) Спасибо за совет. А в данном коде я не понасоздавал лишнего?

Comment: imho вот тут `current->prev=current;` ошибка. Надо `current->prev=p;` (и в начале инициализировать `..., *p = 0;`)

Comment: @avp А, да, действительно, ведь когда у меня выделяется память для первой структуры, то у меня нет структуры, которая указывает на эту, а я беру и записываю туда адрес current.

Comment: И делаете это для **всех** структур

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Во-первых, данное предложение

```
current->prev=current;
```

логически некорректно, так как когда `head` - это и есть `current`, то получается, что предыдущий узел есть текущий узел. Вы должны делать проверку на то, равняется ли `current` `head`, или что `head` равно `NULL`.

Фактически, указатель `p` играет роль узла, указывающего на конец списка, который обычно обозначается как `tail`.

В таких случаях, когда имеется дело с двусвязными списками, то определяют дополнительную структуру, которая содержит два указателя: на начало списка (`head`), и на конец списка (`tail`), Можно также в эту структуру включить член, который будет содержать количество элементов в списке.

Также у вас странное название структуры: `name`.

Ниже представлена упрощенная демонстрационная программа, которая показывает, как можно определить двусвязный список, и как добавлять в него элементы.

Другие функции для работы со списком постарайтесь определить самостоятельно.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Node
{
    int value;
    struct Node *next;
    struct Node *prev;
};

struct List
{
    struct Node *head;
    struct Node *tail;
};

int push_back( struct List *list, int value )
{
    struct Node *tmp = malloc( sizeof( struct Node ) );

    int success = tmp != NULL;

    if ( success )
    {
        tmp->value = value;

        tmp->prev = list->tail;
        tmp->next = NULL;

        if ( list->head == NULL )
        {
            list->head = tmp;
        }

        if ( list->tail != NULL )
        {
            list->tail->next = tmp;
        }           

        list->tail = tmp;
    }

    return success;
}

void print_list( const struct List *list )
{
    for ( struct Node *current = list->head; current != NULL; current = current->next )
    {
        printf( "%d ", current->value );
    }
}

void reverse_print_list( const struct List *list )
{
    for ( struct Node *current = list->tail; current != NULL; current = current->prev )
    {
        printf( "%d ", current->value );
    }
}

int main(void) 
{
    struct List list = { NULL, NULL };
    // или 
    // struct List list = { .head = NULL, .tail = NULL };

    const int N = 10;

    for ( int i = 0; i < N; i++ ) push_back( &list, i );

    print_list( &list );
    putchar( '\n' );

    reverse_print_list( &list );
    putchar( '\n' );

    return 0;
}
```

Вывод программы на консоль:

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0
```

Comment: спасибо за такое подробное и доступное объяснение